# Reading value from TAB delimiter file in batch file

Tags: batch-file

The below data file has TAB delimiter, if all the filed values are available its working fine, if any value is empty in the file its not coming proper. First line data is fetching properly but second line data not fetching properly because 2nd and 4th field is null (there is 2 TAB between 1st and 3rd field and 3rd and 5th in second line). Please help me any changes need to be done in code.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
call :find_data
endlocal
pause
exit /b 0 
:find_data
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,3,5 delims=    " %%a in (data.txt) do (
set id=%%a
set name=%%b
set addr=%%c
echo [!id!] [!name!] [!addr!] 
)
exit /b 0
endlocal
goto :eof
```

`data.txt`:

> ```
> 11111 C   John    K   USA
> 22222     Harry       USA
> ```

Output of above code:

> ```
> [11111] [John] [USA]
> [22222] [USA] []
> ```

Expected output:

> ```
> [11111] [John] [USA]
> [22222] [Harry] [USA]
> ```

Comment: mind that if you use space as a delimiter it should be at the end because of a bug in FOR command:  `for /f "tokens=1,3,5 delims=<tab><space>"`

Comment: @npocmaka, you think it is a bug that the space must be specified as the last character in the option string? Actually I think that is on purpose, because otherwise you could not use the space as separator between the options when `delims` is not the last one...

Comment: There is actually no need for the interim variables `id`, etc....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses a different approach:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "delims=" %%a in (data.txt) do (
   set "data=%%a"
   call :find_data
)
pause
exit /b 0 

:find_data
set i=1
rem Separate individual tokens based on TAB character
set "token1=%data:  =" & set /A i+=1 & set "token!i!=%"
echo [!token1!] [!token3!] [!token5!] 
goto :eof
```

**Important**: Note that the character between colon and equal sign in `%data:  ="` part *must be* a TAB character. This char is usually changed for spaces by the web browser, so you must delete the spaces and insert a TAB.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "tab=   "
call :find_data
pause
GOTO :eof

:find_data
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%T in (%sourcedir%\q46842570.txt) do (
 SET "dataline=%%T"
 SET "dataline="!dataline:%tab%="#"!""
 for /f "tokens=1,3,5 delims=#" %%a in ("!dataline!") do (
  set id=%%~a
  set name=%%~b
  set addr=%%~c
  echo [!id!] [!name!] [!addr!] 
 )
)
endlocal
goto :eof
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q46842570.txt` containing your data for my testing.

I set a variable called `tab` so that I don't get confused.

The problem arises because `cmd` interprets successive delimiters as a single delimiter, so I simply replaced every `tab` with `"#"` in `dataline`. I found that attempting to replace `tab` with `"tab"` failed, so I chose `#` (it just needs to be otherwise-unused in the file) `dataline` is further enclosed in rabbits'-ears so that the result is

> "field1"#"field2"#"field3"#"field4"#"field5"

Then use `#` as the delimiter and remove the enclosing quotes around the field-data appearing in the `metavariables` with (eg) `%%~a`.

---

Following aschipfl's constructive critique, another routine to accomplish this without changing the delimiter is `:find_data2` below:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "tab=   "
call :find_data
 call :find_data2
pause
GOTO :eof

:find_data
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%T in (%sourcedir%\q46842570.txt) do (
 SET "dataline=%%T"
 SET "dataline="!dataline:%tab%="#"!""
 for /f "tokens=1,3,5 delims=#" %%a in ("!dataline!") do (
  set id=%%~a
  set name=%%~b
  set addr=%%~c
  echo [!id!] [!name!] [!addr!] 
 )
)
endlocal
goto :eof

:find_data2
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%T in (%sourcedir%\q46842570.txt) do (
 SET "dataline=%%T"
for /f "tokens=1,3,5 delims=%tab%" %%a in (""!dataline:^%tab%^="%tab%"!"") do (
  set id=%%~a
  set name=%%~b
  set addr=%%~c
  echo [!id!] [!name!] [!addr!] 
 )
)
endlocal
goto :eof
```

Comment: Why should `"TAB"` fail? did you do the sub-string replacement within the set `()` of the `for /F` loop? then you might have unquoted TABs escaped. I used something like this: `@for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%~dpn0.txt") do @(set "LINE=%%L" & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & for /F "tokens=1,3,5 delims= " %%I in (^""!LINE: ="^ "!"^") do @(endlocal & echo [%%~I] [%%~J] [%%~K]))`

Comment: @aschipfl : My first approach was `%%a in ("!dataline:%tab%="%tab%"!") do` and with the `tab`s escaped (both as the variable `%tab%` and a real tab character) and I found that it didn't perform the expected substitution.

Comment: I think it should have been `%%a in (""!dataline:^%tab%^="%tab%"!"") do` as only the first TAB appears unescaped, like the equal-to sign, and the outer-most quotes are consumed by `for /F` to detect that a literal string is given; or you escape the outer-most quotes and change TAB escaping, like `%%a in (^""!dataline:%tab%="^%tab%"!"^") do`; escaping both TABs leads to one literal `^` character...

Comment: @aschipfl : Seems you're correct. `(""!dataline:^%tab%^="%tab%"!"")` worked for me.